# Linux device driver for banana pi and device tree

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

I'm trying to write ethernet driver for Linux kernel 4.13.x for Banana Pi M2 ultra.
Some time ago so called "device tree" (DT) has been introduced in Linux kernel infrastructure.
I have no much experience with using DT while writing device drivers and because of that
I've got a few questions.

As far as I know - in case of banana pi system - it is needed to provide some clock source for given 
peripheral device. It is function of CCU in banana pi to provide such a clock. The CCU is memory mapped
resource available at some address in the linux kernel. I'd like to write driver for ethernet which 
needs some clock from CCU.

I know that physical address of CCU must be mapped via ioremap() or similar function to virtual address.

My question is how can I fetch the virtual address of CCU in my ethernet driver? Is it possible to do via
device tree? If yes - how to do this? Or maybe this virtual address can be get another way?

I'm just not sure if it is done (fetching virt address) via DT or just by some procedure or via global pointer.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Your driver should not *"fetch the virtual address of CCU"*.  The kernel uses object-oriented techniques such as data encapsulation so that drivers do not share such address or data.  There should be some function your driver can call to acquire or enable the necessary clock.

Answer (score 1):

There are examples in Linux kernel for platform drivers. I have worked on i2c and i2s on raspberry pi so I can quote those examples.

In http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.3.2/source/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-bcm2835.c

Look at the probe function, it calls the subsystem api

```
platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_MEM, 0);
```

This can gives physical address which is ioremap ..

For this it is required to create a device node in device tree as in
https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.9.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/bcm283x.dtsi

check for i2c0 device node in file bcm283x.dtsi.

The reg key is where physical address is stored

```
reg = <0x7e205000       0x1000>;

        physical add     size
```

Hope this help you.

Device tree may be considered analogus to platform data previously

Comment: Either I don't get your point or you missed my point. I'm not looking for the way where to place the physical address, but rather how to share virtual address of CCU between all the peripheral devices which needs to use this CCU. Every peripheral driver needs to use CCU virtual address to configure properly the clock for it. So this is the relation 1:n - many drivers uses virtual address from one of the peripheral (CCU).  The main issue for me is to how to get access to this virtual address of CCU?

Comment: This can be done through device tree. create a device node for CCU clock and you can share the device node to all the peripheral devices which require it. You can use the concept of phandle of device tree. See how clocks device node is shared between different nodes.. https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.9.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/bcm283x.dtsi. Hopefully I have understood your question

Comment: The correct way to do is to use click framework properly as pointed by @sawdust.